# Drag and drop images in Windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create an app in Windows phone 7.1 in which a Scrollviewer containing images is present in a horizontal row if we drag an image to the position of other image the positions should change among the images so that no images should collide each other.how can I make it in WP7?